# Was Vs Had in the context of There

Tags: grammar

I'm a beginner in English just trying to learn it and sometimes I've really got confused what to use. Can anyone help me to about this context?

Which one is correct ?

1. In the middle of the area there **was** a hotel.
2. In the middle of the area there **used to be** a hotel.
3. In the middle of the area there **had** a hotel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two are correct.
The third is wrong as it stands. As stangdon says in their comment (thanks for that), it would be correct if it was changed to:

> In the middle of the area there had **been** a hotel.

In which case it means the same as your second example.

The first example can have different meanings depending on context.

> In the middle of the area there was a hotel.

- In the middle of the area there exists a hotel. *"In the middle of the area there was a hotel, where we stayed the night"* The hotel may well still be there.
- *"In the middle of the area there was a hotel, but it is now an apartment block"*  This is exactly the same as your second example "used to be". The hotel no longer exists.

Comment: The third is wrong but you might want to explain why it's wrong - if it were "there had *been* a hotel" it would be right...

Comment: @stangdon Thanks for that, I've updated my answer and, hopefully, improved it in other ways.